# Why doesn't TextBoxFor include validation elements if called twice for the same model property?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Simple question... Here is an example of some razor code:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(c => c.RevisedEstimate)
@Html.TextBoxFor(c => c.RevisedEstimate)
```

Here is how this renders:

```
<input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Revised Estimate must be a number." id="RevisedEstimate" name="RevisedEstimate" type="text" value="0" />
<input id="RevisedEstimate" name="RevisedEstimate" type="text" value="0" />
```

The obvious question you ask is, "Why are you doing that?". The razor view is actually building client side detail-row templates that are used in KendoUI grids. There are two similar grids and we use the same viewmodel server side. We actually do provide the id element for the template so each field in each row ends up with a unique id.

Why does the second input element not have the data-val and data-val-number elements?

Comment: Just a guess, but probably because they have the same id. The validation scripts finds the first one and gives it the attributes.

Comment: Is there a practical reason to have 2 inputs for the same property?

Comment: These are actually building client templates for KendoUI grids. So yes, there is a practical reason.

Comment: So in that case give them (or one of them) unique id, because the document is not valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since we were generating HTML for use in a client side template what we did was just create a variable to hold the HTML generated by the helper, and then render out that code in the Views..

Something like:

```
@{
   var revisedEstimateInput = Html.TextBoxFor(c => c.RevisedEstimate)
}
```

Then later in the view:

```
@(revisedEstimateInput)
```

...in as many places as needed. This way the validation and other metadata attributes were in place in our client templates and all the kenodUI validation worked correctly.

Comment: This works ok, but for example I have to set custom classes for each field. The first field should have class 'field1', the second 'field2' and so on. Do you know a way to achieve this ? var revisedEstimateInput = Html.TextBoxFor(c => c.RevisedEstimate, new { @class = 'field1') })

Answer (score 2):

Off the top of my head knowing what the JS does in the background, it seems to do this to prevent conflicts. The JS looks for the elements with the data- attributes to do it's validation, along with other functions, so it could possibly pick the wrong one if there are multiple instances of it.